# if condition not working in the expected manner

Tags: php, if-statement

the current page is getting the variables item and code from query string,so according to my code it should go into any of the first three conditions... but its going into the last else conditon.. while echoing the values $a and $i, i am getting 2 and A-1-1 respectively.

```
$a=$_GET['code'];
$i=$_GET['item'];
if($a==1 && $i!='')
{
  header("location:http//:www.abc.com");
}
else if($a==2 && $i!='')
{
  header("location:http://www.xyz.com");
}
else if($a==3  && $i!='')
{
 header("location:http://www.xpqr.com");
}
else if($a==1)
{
  header("location: http://www.a1bc.com");
}
else if($a==2)
{
  header("location:http://www.x1yz.com");
}
else if($a==3)
{
  header("location:http://www.x1pqr.com");
}
else
{
   echo "ERROR";
}
```

can someone help me find the issue why the if else not working in the expected manner.

Comment: You're assigning `$a = 1` instead of comparing `$a == 1`. You can use [Yoda conditions](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions) to avoid this problem: `1 == $a`. `1 = $a` will throw an error.

Comment: Sorry that was an error while posting..!still the problem persist..

Comment: user "<>" to compare instead of "!="

Comment: @MahavirMunot.. done that... but itsn't working..

Comment: Mahavir Munot is just trolling. `<>` is the same as `!=` as descibed [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). I wish I had a minus on that answer...

Comment: I tested your script locally and it works fine.

Comment: code seems ok.. just sayin, try !empty($i) instead of $i!=''

Comment: thank you all for all your valuable comments... i just removed the space inside if conditons "else if($a==3&&$i!='') " and it worked perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

In conditions you are writing

```
if($a=1 && $i!='')  // "=" is assignment operator
```

it should bt

```
if($a==1 && $i!='')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the equality operator: `==`  double equal

```
if($a==1 && $i!='')
```

single equal is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operator instead of a conditional operator.
For the above code the value of a will always be `1` because of the following line of code :

```
if($a=1 && $i!='')
```

`=` is an assignment operator where as `==` is a conditional operator.

Use `==` in all your if condition.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` in all your if condition. And your header codes

```
header("location: http:www.abc.com");
```

Should be like this

```
header("location: http://www.abc.com"); // you are missing '//' in every header
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               $a=$_GET['code'];
               $i=$_GET['item'];
               if($a==1 && !$i)
                {
                 header("location:http//:www.abc.com");
                }
                else if($a==2 && !$i)
                 {
                    header("location:http://www.xyz.com");
                 }
                 else if($a==3  && !$i)
                 {
                  header("location:http://www.xpqr.com");
                 }
                 else if($a==1)
                  {
                 header("location: http://www.a1bc.com");
                  }
                  else if($a==2)
                  {
                   header("location:http://www.x1yz.com");
                   }
                  else if($a==3)
                  {
                   header("location:http://www.x1pqr.com");
                   }
                    else
                  {
                 echo "ERROR";
                     }
```

use !$i it sets to false.